# Upgrading BIOS dell vostro 5590 from USB

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, dell, usb-drive, bios

I have a Dell vostro 5590, which overheats under Kubuntu 20.04 (the CPU cores reaching 90+ degrees regularly, so is the package temperature, fans working often at top speed).

I currently have BIOS version 1.8.2, and I have seen [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-il/product-support/product/vostro-15-5590-laptop/drivers) that the newest version is 1.11 (from the 1st of September 2020). Thus, I hope that if I upgrade my bios to the newest version, it will be fixed.

In [this](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-il/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en) article, Dell are suggesting to create a blank bootable device, and to move the bios-upgrade `.exe` file to it, booting into the bios (using F12) and updating.

This far, I have tried to create a live USB using:

1. The `KDE partition manager`, deleting all partitions and making one partition using FAT32.
2. Using `rufus` on windows to create a bootable device using freeBSD (a long shot).
3. Using `diskpart` according to the steps [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-il/sln153364/create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-using-the-diskpart-utility?lang=en) changing from ntfs to FAT32.

So far, when I reach the bios, it doesn't seem to recognize this as a bootable device, in any of the cases above, and when I'm trying the "Upgrade BIOS" option in the BIOS, I get nothing (no option to choose a file or anything active...).

**Remark 1:** from the same USB I was installing Kubuntu 20.04 on this machine, so it is working, checked it out before this process.

**Remark 2:** I have the `dell recovery utility` on another USB drive, and it recognizes it, and even boots into it.

Comment: Have you a spare usb to try with it?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity No, my only "spare" USB is holding the dell recovery utility, and is much older. As I said, I was able to boot from it just before I have tried these steps.

Comment: I suggested this because something similar heppened to me, and using a different usb solved the problem.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity unfortunately I don't have another one...